# ¿Cómo saber el tipo de pc que estoy usando?

Tags: consola, powershell, terminal

Me gustaría saber si existe algún comando por consola que diga el tipo de computador que se está usando, es decir, computador de escritorio, laptop, etc.

Comment: Escritorio, laptop, etc? Cuántos tipos crees que hay en ese `etc`? Hay sistemas embedidos, virtualizados y pare de contar, por lo cual la lista se hace grande.

Comment: Creo que puedes obtener info del PC pero no de su naturaleza (por llamarla de alguna manera). En todo caso, para qué sistema operativo? Porque eso reduce las posibles soluciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de Windows, puedes usar de la clase [Win32_SystemEnclosure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemenclosure), la propiedad `ChassisTypes`.

```
wmic systemenclosure get chassistypes
```

Other (1), Unknown (2), Desktop (3), Low Profile Desktop (4), ... Laptop (9), Notebook (10), ... etc. El listado completo en el enlace proporcionado.

Ver [más al respecto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55184682/1545868).

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me es muy útil tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa, si es bajo Windows:

```
(Get-Computerinfo).CSPCSystemType
```

Get-Computerinfo es un cmdlet que obtiene muchos de los mismos datos que obtiene WMI.  La propriedad CSPCSystemType contiene Desktop, Laptop, etc.

No sé si Get-ComputerInfo corre lo mismo bajo otros SO.